# windows 7: restrict file access to the exe while executing it from command line

Tags: windows-7

I want to run an exe from the command line. I do not create this exe. 
I am running this exe as a non-admin user
There might be code in the exe that might access folders that it shouldn't be accessing. Can I restrict access by passing command line options.
I need to run the exe multiple times. Each time I need to restrict the access to different folders.

I cannot change the user under which the program is running each time.

Example:

run 1: can access only c:\programdata\data1
run 2: can access only c:\programdata\data10

and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that impossible as a limited user, since you cannot restrict access calls as such.  The only surefire way of restricting file access is using ACL permissions, since all file access in Windows goes through ACL permissions.